What does order means in $L_p$ space
I know $L_p$ space is defined $\mathcal{L_p} / \sim$, where $f\sim g$ iff $f=g$ almost surely. I encounter so many things like 'suppose $X, Y \in L_p$, $X\leq Y$.' in probability theory. For example,
One property of conditional expectation is , suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables in $L_1[\Omega, \mathcal{F},\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{P}]$, $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of  $\mathcal{F}$.
If $X \leq Y$, then $E[X|\mathcal{A}] <= E[Y|\mathcal{A}]$
The conditional expectation is defined here as a unique element in $L_1[\Omega, \mathcal{F},\Bbb{R}, \mathcal{P}]$ satisfying the characteristic, which is an equivalent class. So What does the ordering mean here? How to compare two equivalence class? Can we define it in certain way such it can be a partial order (even better as Total order)?

Can you give a specific example from a specific text?  I can think of at least two different interpretations right off the top of my head, so without more details, I'm afraid that the question is kind of unanswerable.

There are several ways to describe what the order on $L^p$ is.
The order on $L^p$
If $\dot f$ and $\dot g$ are elements of $L^p$, i.e. equivalence classes of $\mathcal L^p$ functions modulo equality almost everywhere, it can easily be checked that the following conditions are equivalent:

there exists a representative $f$ of $\dot f$ and a representative $g$ of $\dot g$ such that $f\leq g$ everywhere;
there exists a representative $f$ of $\dot f$ and a representative $g$ of $\dot g$ such that $f\leq g$ almost everywhere;
for every representative $f$ of $\dot f$ and every representative $g$ of $\dot g$, $f\leq g$ almost everywhere.

These conditions on $\dot f$ and $\dot g$ being fulfilled is what is meant by $\dot f\leq\dot g$.
Using the third condition, it is not difficult to see that this does define an order on $L^p$ and that this order in general is not total (for example, on $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, consider the equivalence classes of the indicator functions $1_{[0,1/2]}$ and $1_{[1/2,1]}$).
Despite being only partial in general, this order is still a very good order to work with because it makes $L^p$ a Riesz space which is always Dedekind complete when $1\leq p<\infty$, and is still Dedekind complete when $p=\infty$ for a large class of measure spaces which includes most commonly encountered measure spaces (in particular, probability spaces and measure spaces given by a Radon measure).
For details for $1\leq p<\infty$, see Bourbaki's Integration, chap. IV, § 3, no. 6, especially prop. 14 and its second corollary. For details for $p=\infty$, see the paper Equivalence of measure spaces by Segal, especially section 5 and its theorem 5.1.
Additional properties
This order on $L^p$ satisfy some other interesting general properties which suggest it is certainly the order on $L^p$ which is the most appropriate to consider.
As usual, endow $\mathcal L^p$ with the usual order for functions (i.e. $f\leq g$ means $f\leq g$ everywhere). The quotient map from $\mathcal L^p$ to $L^p$ can be checked to be increasing. Moreover, using the first of the three conditions characterizing the order of $L^p$, the following property can be seen to hold :
A function $\Phi$ defined on $L^p$ and taking its values in an ordered set $F$ is increasing if and only if the function from $\mathcal L^p$ to $F$ obtained by composing $\Phi$ with the quotient map is increasing.
In other words, the "structure" of ordered set on $L^p$, when "homomorphisms" of ordered sets are taken to be the increasing maps, is none other than the "final structure" with respect to the quotient map. Using this property, various instances of "universal property of the quotient" can be proven…
